# AttributeError: module 'object_detection.utils.config_util' has no attribute 'update_fine_tune_checkpoint_type'

Tags: python, attributeerror, object-detection-api, tensorflow1.15

Good day, I am working on an object detection project and the title is the error that I am getting.
This error occurs when I try to train the model

The model im using is my_ssd_mobnet
im using tensorflow 1.15

I am just running a python code as shown and I am stucked here
Please help!

I was running a code, and i am expecting for the model to be trained,, but the error prevents that,,, I think there is problem with the train loop function but i do not know how to fix it.

Comment: Welcome.. your code please?